# Want to use the Windows Media Player > Visualizations> Alchemy in full screen respond to line in signal

Tags: audio, plugins, windows-media-player

I think my favorite thing about Windows from XP to 8.1 is the Windows Media Player visualization (named) "Alchemy" in full screen.  Is there a way to make it respond to a signal coming from the line in jack? (or any alternate source of audio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download VLC Media Player
2. Create stream from input device
3. Open Stream in Windows Media Player
4. Swap view to now playing and set visualization.

- 

```
Open VLC and choose "Media > Open Capture Device"

Capture Mode: DirectShow
Video Device Name: None
Audio Device Name:  Your desired input device

Bottom right play button, hit the down arrow and choose "Stream"

New window opens > Hit Next
New Destination: Dropdown to "MS-WMSP (MMSH)
Click ADD button
Address:  127.0.0.1
Port: 8080
Choose Next

Check Active Transcoding
Choose "Audio-MP3" from dropdown 
Choose Next
Click Stream  (leave "stream all elementary streams unchecked")

Now you have the VLC stream configured. 

Open Windows Media Player
Press ALT key for file menu
File > Open URL >  mms://127.0.0.1:8080

Press ALT key again 
View > Now Playing
Right click the middle of the screen
Visualizations > Alchemy > Random
```

Now you should hear your input device out of your speakers as well see it change the alchemy movements.